I want to personalize the output images of a deepimagesearch vgg19 CNN result - How do I go about it?
I am using the python library deepimagesearch.
This is the code:
from DeepImageSearch import Load_Data, Search_Setup

image_list = Load_Data().from_folder(['folder_path'])

ssup = Search_Setup(image_list=image_list, model_name='vgg19', pretrained=True, image_count=400)

st.plot_similar_images(image_path='image_path', number_of_images=9)

I got this from an online code repository and need to tweek it for my usage.
Also,
Can the code be further tweeked to define the numnber of patches to be used since the deepimagesearch library is a vision transformer library.
I tried this:
from DeepImageSearch import Load_Data, Search_Setup
image_list = Load_Data().from_folder(['folder_path'])
ssup = Search_Setup(image_list=image_list, model_name='vgg19', pretrained=True, image_count=400)
st.plot_similar_images(image_path='image_path', number_of_images=9)

I expect to personalize my search result.

Try to put code in block
i.e.
import sys

